# Linear regulator power consumption

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, voltage-regulator, detector

I have this circuit linear regulator with UVLO so I would like to calculate the power consumption of this block any person can help me, please
Vout = 1.5 V (Iss = 15.2 μA, Vout = 1.5 V, switching = 32.768 kHz, δ = 0.809),
block function A 1.5-V low dropout (LDO) linear regulator Torex XC6215B with quiescent current consumption 0.8-μA. Below 1.5 V, the input of the linear regulator is disconnected from the supercapacitor by a p-type MOSFET (Si-2302) in order to avoid leakage current. An XC6120C voltage detector turns the low-side switch on when 1.5 V is reached across the storage element[image]

Comment: what is the range of input voltage/energy source/supercap to generate 1.5V at the output & what is the consumption on 1.5V (load)?

Comment: the input voltage range  1.5 to 4.5 V  the power extracted of the electromagnetic energy harvesting 150µW the supercap 4.5V 11.5mF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power lost in a linear regulator is equal to the voltage drop between input and output times the output current plus the input voltage times the current flowing to ground through the linear regulator.

\$P = (V_{in}-V_{out})I_{load} + V_{in}I_{gnd}\$

When there is no load, we have

\$P_{quiescent} = V_{in}I_{quiescent}\$

When there is full load, it is generally the case that

\$I_{load} >> I_{gnd}\$

and we can often safely ignore \$I_{gnd}\$

giving us

\$P_{loaded} \approx (V_{in}-V_{out})I_{load}\$

You mention in a comment that the highest \$V_{in}\$ will be 4.5V. In that case, the voltage drop from \$V_{in}\$ to your load will be 3.0V. Multiply that by \$I_{load}\$ and you will have approximately your maximum power consumption of your regulator.

If your input voltage drops to exactly 1.5V, even a low drop-out regulator will not deliver exactly 1.5V under a non-trivial load. In trying to maintain output voltage, \$I_{gnd}\$ may increase significantly above \$I_{quiescent}\$. You may want to choose a voltage detector whose tripping voltage is above your regulator IC's minimum suggested operating \$V_{in}\$ to avoid that problem.

According to the [XC6125 Datasheet](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc6215/XC6215.pdf) p.33, the dropout voltage at 1.5V output may be as high as 890mV. So, you may want your voltage detector to trip at 2.390V to avoid operating below the drop-out voltage range.

Comment: Think you very much how I can calculated the power consumption in si-2302 just I will know the steps

Comment: The power consumption of the series FET is included in the formula \$(V_{in}-V_{out})I_{load}\$. The power consumption of the FET fed by the detector is negligible. You can treat the 1M\$\Omega\$ resistor and FET together as a 1M\$\Omega\$ resistor without much error.

Comment: the problem is in the current drain I don't know how I can calculate it,

Comment: The current drain of the load? The quiescent current drain of the LDO? The current drain of the detector or the current drain of the 2M\$\Omega\$ + FET shunt?

Comment: the current drain of the 2MΩ + FET shunt and the drain load

Comment: The 2M\$\Omega\$ + FET use: Current = 4.5V/2M\$\Omega\$ = 2.25\$\mu\$A. Power \$= (4.5V)^2/2M\Omega = 10\mu\$W.

Comment: What exactly is your load?

Comment: ok thank you very much