# How to calculate the power draw and current draw of a PCB

Tags: power, pcb, current, pcb-design

I have a PCB my team designed that is based on an Adafruit board (Feather M0 LoRa), makes use of several breakout boards (temp sensor, IMU, etc.), and has various other components such as LEDs, resistors, charge capacitors, and voltage regulators. I've been looking into how calculate both current draw and power draw of the PCB to determine the battery that we should be using and to get a better of idea of the power consumption of the circuit.

My current approach to calculating current draw involves identifying the components that are expected to have the greatest impact on current consumption. I sum up their individual current consumption values as indicated on their datasheets, and then multiply this sum by the desired operational time of the PCB. This calculation gives me an estimate of the milliampere-hour (mAh) rating needed for the battery. Since some breakout boards have different power states, I plan to account for this by modeling the time spent in each state and averaging out the current consumption. This approach will help me determine the total mAh requirement for the battery.

As for power consumption, since I know all the boards in my PCB run on 3.3V, I would just make use of \$P = IV\$, where \$V = 3.3\$ and \$I\$ is the current consumption sum I calculated before.

My question when it comes to these two calculations is if I'm even doing any of this correctly. One glaring issue with these calculations is the fact that I leave out other components that could have a hand in these results such as the LEDs, resistors, charge capacitors, and voltage regulators. I wasn't sure how they played a part in here so I left them out. I also think my power draw calculations are just flat out wrong. If anyone has some insight or experience in this, I would appreciate the help a lot.

Comment: Surely you create the pcb to hold a working circuit so the current flow - both total and in all paths is already known? otherwise how did you get the trace widths?

Comment: I didn't know that was the case, for context I'm just in charge of programming the board, another person in my team designed the PCB. I brought this up with them and it seems like they just overestimated trace widths to ensure the max possible current draw and followed "rule of thumb stuff". So it seems like we don't have an exact number for current flow.

Comment: why don't you measure it?

Comment: The PCB hasn't been soldered together yet. I also wanted to take a more methodological approach and calculate the current draw and power budget and to see if it matches my team's target lifetime with some batteries we were considering on using. After doing that and with a soldered board, I intended to cross verify the calculations with physical measurements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you elaborate on why you think your calculations are wrong?

You are on the right track with your initial approach to modeling the system, but it depends on your needed level of accuracy.  Model everything as power (current * voltage), as you said.

You should indeed include things like LEDs and the voltage regulators in your analysis.  A LED could burn up to 20mA if its very bright.

For LEDs, you should know the on current, voltage and time.

For regulators, you know the voltage in, voltage out, current and efficiency (from the datasheet.)  The efficiency is important because a linear regulator will burn a lot of power compared to a buck/boost regulator.

Unless you have high current AC you can ignore inductors and capacitors in your model.

You also might want to include the internal resistance of the battery.

For any microcontrollers the datasheet should have values for its power consumption at a specified frequency.  For example uA/Mhz.

Things can get complicated when you start including misc microcontroller sub systems such as ADCs, serial ports, etc.  If you know you are using these then look at the datasheet to get an idea of the power consumption.

Does the lora device provide values for its transmit and receive power consumption?  If yes, then you will need to know how long the LoRa module is on communicating int order to get a rough model.

Then multiply everything by 10% to compensate for error :-)

Put all of these models into a spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet is a nice way to create a table of power consumption per sub system, and time.

Modelling is helpful, but in reality, it can take weeks to do it well, and measurement is your best bet to verify your model anyway. A lot of times we will start off with a model spreadsheet, but slowly replace the theoretical numbers with real measurements.

Measurement can be tricky at low current since many high resolution DMMs such as the Keithley's of the world can be quite expensive.

Comment: I'm doubting my calculations because it's my first time doing this, and I can't easily verify them so I'm a bit skeptical of my work. For the voltage regulator, I found its efficiency to be 83.33%. So, would my power consumption be the calculated power assuming 100% efficiency, multiplied by 83.33%? And regarding the microcontroller, there's no information on power consumption for IC2 and SPI connections. Can I simply include the current it uses in my current draw sum for power calculations?

Comment: If its a buck/boost then yes divide the total power you expect the regulator to supply by .8333.  If its a linear regulator then you can calculate power lost with the method described in the link below  Which is (Vin-Vout)*current
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536935/linear-regulator-power-consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate power draw but if you have a microprocessor that can be much more difficult because of the routines running on the processor will affect the power. There are ways to model this but it is very difficult in time-consuming it would be easier to build the PCB and then measure the power.

One thing you can do is estimate max power from the data sheets but that won't help you very much if you aren't running your processor with max current all of the time.

If you have any other components you should try and estimate the power draw from each component. You may need to average over time as some components turn on and off only for a short time